# Using Thread in Android for sending message

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-alertdialog

I have this code:

```
 if (value) {
            thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while (!isConnected()) {
                            synchronized (this) {
                                wait(3000);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }

                    if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
                        sendMessageWidget();
                    } else {
                        showWifiSettingsAlert();
                    }
                }
            };

            thread.start();
        }
```

I want my app to wait until google api client is connected and than send a message.

The code for the isConnected method is:

```
public boolean isConnected() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But I get this error message: 
NullPointerException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(), and it says that the mistake is somewhere id showWifiSettingsAlert()

here is the code:

```
public void showWifiSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Location accuracy tips");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("You can improve the accuracy of your location by turning on\n- Wi-Fi");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Turn on",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
//                       Posalji poruke al pre toga jos jednom azuriraj
//                       lokaciju al ako je pozvana aplikacija iz widgeta
                        if (value) {
                            sendMessageWidget();
                        }
                    }
                });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

                        // Posalji poruke al pre toga jos jednom azuriraj
                        // lokaciju al ako je pozvana aplikacija iz widgeta
                        if (value) {
                            sendMessageWidget();
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

I want, if wifi is not enabled, the user to choose to enable it or not, but either way the message should be sent... can you help please?

Comment: Because you are trying to create or update Application View  from worker thread and android doesn't allowed that because you have to call view related code in Main Application UI Thread only, as I don't know what codes in `sendMessageWidget();` so just put `showWifiSettingsAlert();` in `runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: Do this using Handler or Use runOnUiThread ,
Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9110251/3530653

Comment: sendMessageWidget just sends the message from the widget, nothing special

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't touch the UI from a thread other than the main thread, you must post these changes back to the UI thread and its looper and associated handlers. You can do so explicitly by creating a handler associated with the UI thread (which will work anywhere, since `Looper.getMainLooper()` is a static call) such as:

```
if (value) {
            Handler uiCallback = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while (!isConnected()) {
                            synchronized (this) {
                                wait(3000);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }

                    uiCallback.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override public void run() {
                            if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
                                sendMessageWidget();
                            } else {
                                showWifiSettingsAlert();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            };

            thread.start();
        }
```

Or instead of using a handler at all, you can wrap the part in the `run()` method in `runOnUiThread()` if you are in an activity which does the same thing.

You should note however, you don't actually need to use any threading here. If you follow the example on: https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html you'll find that by implementing `ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener` you can call `mGoogleApis.connect()` from the activity's `onStart()` and when it connects or fails to do the corresponding callback will be executed on the calling thread. For instance,

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
     if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
         sendMessageWidget();
     } else {
         showWifiSettingsAlert();
     }
}
```

Achieves the same thing...

Comment: No problem, `Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` is handy trick whenever you need to get back to the main thread :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `mGoogleApiClient.connect();`, which is an asynchronous method, in a thread and this isn't allowed.

You could try using `runOnUiThread` instead :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //do your stuff here
                }
            });
```

Comment: You can totally call this from any thread: that it is asynchronous just means it will return without blocking the current thread from executing until it is or fails to connect. Technically the op should handle the callback appropiatly--that is, wait until the callback is triggered; then he wouldn't have to worry about threading at all. But that wasn't his original question.